# Change the content of a Label from a UserControls

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, user-controls, window

I have created a UserControl called `UserControl1` and added it into my **MainWindow**.

What I want is that when the user clicks on the `add` button on the UserControl the label called `data` in the **MainWindow** has its content changed.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication6.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="add" x:Name="add"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

<Window x:Class="WpfApplication6.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        xmlns:WpfApplication6="clr-namespace:WpfApplication6"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Label Content="data" x:Name="data"/>
            <WpfApplication6:UserControl1 x:Name="myUC"/>
    </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: You can bind label content to userControl property. When add button is pressed, userControl will set property and label will change

Comment: I tried ICommand, DependencyProperty, ... and nothing worked. so I created a new project and now I'm asking you help (I want some code exampels)

Comment: And why voting down my question ?

Comment: Have you considered the MVVM pattern?

Comment: @HenkHolterman No one gived me an answer for what I asked so I created a new one with more details.

Comment: @Wassim You were given a great (and correct) answer to your question the first time you asked it.  Additionally, you are free to edit your question at any time to add additional information.

Comment: @Wassim : you should now be asking specific questions about either events or commands. This is just a repeat, only a small edit of the previous question.

Answer (score 1):

Define a property in userControl say `NewData`, don't forget to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` Iterface.

Bind label content to userControl.NewData Property:

```
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=myUC, Path=NewData" x:Name="data"/>
```

When userControl's button is pressed, set required data to NewData property

[How to: Implement Property Change Notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx)

Comment: How can I implement INotifyPropertyChanged ?

Comment: Your class should inherit INotifyPropertyChanged interface and then, Call PropertyChanged event in the property's `Setter`. `PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("NewData"));`